# How to Set A secondary Debugging software in Windows 10 TaskManager Debug

Tags: windows-10, task-manager, debug, firefox-quantum, browser-plugin

I would like to know if there is a way to add a secondary
debugging software, to the right click context menu
of the TaskManager, Prefferably SublimeText Editor 3,
or any other similar software, currently the only one
that is available to Select is Visual Studio,
But when i click to choose this one
it says the setup for visual studio is not complete,
Even though I've installed it & all its core packages
multiple times, aswell as unistalling and re-installing
it. My Windows Version is 2004 OS build 19041.508,
With All the latest updates, Drivers are All up to date aswell as .net frameworks..
[image]

It is the Flash Plugin that keeps crashing, even though this is also brand new the newest updated version available. Can Anyone suggest any fixes, even if the be external software, but as a last resort..

Comment: I'm not too sure what you're trying to achieve... As far as I know Sublime does not include any debugger.

Comment: @user1532080 No, guess not. Otherwise it would probably show in the selection menu, maybe have to download an external software... Was just wondering if you could view the source code in Sublime text editor or even the javascript console in browser. but not sure...

Comment: Ok... I've answered your question, but then I guess this isn't what you want to know. You're not going to view any source code, if VS debugger would run, all you'd see is assembler. You should probably ask another question explaining what your problem is and what your goal is. Are you having issues with Firefox running at startup? Are you developing some Flash stuff that crashes flash plugins?...

Comment: @user1532080 Thank you, No I was just on a website that heavily relys on Flash & it kept crashing the web-page. Found that in Taskmanager if I open the Firefox Processes and Kill/Stop the task "Plugin-Container" it fixes the problem but only for about 5 minutes then have to keep re-doing it. Submitted a crash report to firefox so hopefully they fix it sooner or later.. Was just curious to learn more about it.. No issues with firefox at startup.

Answer (score 0):

This article will tell you how to change the JIT debugger: [Enabling Postmortem Debugging](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/enabling-postmortem-debugging)

Now the way you'd get that popup I assume is by choosing "Debug" in context menu. That means you're trying to attach a debugger, if you actually have one, it probably has an option to attach to a running process.